# input file - возможно ли

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как релаизовать следующий сценарий:

1. Вот загружаем мы например мультиселектом через input file 3 файла.
2. Я вывел название файлов ниже инпута.

Теперь у меня стоит задача добавить крестик справа к каждому файлу и при клике на крестик удалить прикрепленный файл + при новой загрузке через инпут не чистить ранее добавленные файлы, а прикрепить новые файлы к уже существующим. Это реально сделать?

Comment: Да, такое сделать реально. А теперь ваш код

Comment: Это называется привью (пред просмотр) `FileReader` вам в помощь.

Comment: Там кода много. Подскажите просто, как сделать чтобы при новой загрузке файлы не перезатерались, а добавлялись к текущим

Comment: Просто тогда делайте сами. Я вам сказал, что нужно, читаем, практикуемся. (каков вопрос, таков ответ).

Comment: @WoodRest, перезатираются только те, которые в коллекции files у инпута, их можно сохранить в отдельную переменную

Comment: А если таких инпутов сотни. Не будем же мы отдельно для каждого store.file создавать. Как в таком случае лучше поступить?

Comment: @WoodRest, не понял твой комментарий